# I want to choose the overloaded function by a template class's type, by way of storing the type in a member. Can I do this?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, overloading, member-functions

I have a working example here:

```cpp
#include <QString>
#include <QUrl>
class Foobar
{
    explicit Foobar( QString fun ) { }
};

template<typename T>
class QPizza
{
public:
    explicit QPizza() { }
    QString value   () { return this->topping(m_T); }

protected:

    virtual QString topping(T*)
    {
        return "this is a T";
    }
    virtual QString topping(QString*)
    {
        return "this is a qstring";
    }
    virtual QString topping(QUrl   *)
    {
        return "This is a url";
    }
    virtual QString topping(Foobar *)
    {
        return "This is a foobar";
    }
private:
    T *m_T{nullptr};
};
```

This allows me to execute the following code:

```cpp
qDebug() << QPizza<QString>().value() << QPizza<Foobar>().value() ;
// "this is a qstring" "This is a foobar"
```

This is great, in that it allows me to basically do specialization without any cumbersome  template syntax.

Here is the problem:

```cpp
    QString topping(QString ) // I'd rather have this
    QString topping(QString*) // instead of this because
    QPizza<QString>().value() // I want <QString> to be synonymous with (QString ), not (QString*)
```

However if I change `T *m_T{nullptr}` to `T m_T;`, then `QPizza<Foobar>()` ceases to work, because it's constructor requires an argument neccessarily.

Is there any way to achieve my goal, so that if I or anyone else chooses to subclass, that the process of overloading `QString topping( <SomeType> );` is a little bit more straight forward?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to to do basically the same thing as  `QString value   () { return PizzaTopping<T>::topping(); }`, with declared specializations of `PizzaTopping<T>` declaring a static inline method return the appropriate topping? This does not require a throwaway variable just for the purposes of overload resolution.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, I am trying to do specialization just like that. The reason why I have not done it in this case is the syntax is awfully cumbersome to make work inline a template class. I actually gave up to be quite honest because once I realized what was needed, I thought that this was actually simpler and more maintainable.

Comment: Well, this actually creates an otherwise pointless class member. I'm not sure what so cumbersome here. I would think that using a dummy class member is the cumbersome part.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik In my working example, the pointless class member is nothing but a `nullptr` of `T` -- The worst you can say about it other than what I already have, is that it is a heterodox means of achieving specialization. That being said, I would love it if you were able to show the class that I made using your method, and have it be less cumbersome to deal with. I'm definitely open to being proven wrong.

Comment: If someone "chooses to subclass" what class? You can't add overloads of `topping` except in the `QPizza` definition with all the others. (CRTP could work around this, but then you'd want a somewhat different setup.)

Comment: @aschepler You can overload topping in a subclass. I don't know what you are talking about. I didn't mark it virtual so I'll go ahead and do that, if thats what you are talking about.

Comment: Whether virtual or not, adding additional overloads of `topping` in a class which inherits `QPizza<T>` will not change the behavior of `QPizza<T>::value()` at all.

Comment: @aschepler I don't know what you mean, because Depending on the type of T, that will be the function that is chosen. `QPizza<QString>::value()` uses the QString overload, and so on.

Comment: Sure, that's one of the four overloads, and yes, a subclass can override `topping(QString*)`. I thought you meant something about adding `topping(SomeOtherType*)` in a subclass to get more than those four overloads.

Comment: @aschepler That is accurate. The way you can do that is because the base class has this: `virtual QString topping(T*)` -- That is actually a bit of a bug though, I realized a few minutes ago because it will clash with existing overloads if the T matches them, but I can get around that by making a base without the other overloads. ( I think )

Comment: Maybe it was the terminology: defining `class Pizza2 : public QPizza<Sardines> { QString topping(Sardines*); };` defines an *override* and does not *overload* anything. I can't really see what the advantage of any of this is supposed to be, though.

Comment: @aschepler Yes. I suppose you are right.  When I subclass, I am not overloading, but merely overriding the placeholder function which is overloaded itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to dispatch according to type:

- function specialization

  ```
  template <typename T>
  QString PizzaTopping() { return "this is a T"; }

  template <> QString PizzaTopping<QString>() { return "this is a qstring"; }
  template <> QString PizzaTopping<QUrl>() { return "this is a url"; }
  template <> QString PizzaTopping<Foobar>() { return "this is a foobar"; }
  ```

  You cannot partial specialize function though
- class specialization

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct PizzaTopping {
      QString operator() const { return "this is a T"; }
  };

  template <>
  struct PizzaTopping<QString> {
      QString operator() const { return "this is a qstring"; }
  };
  template <>
  struct PizzaTopping<QUrl> {
      QString operator() const { return "this is a url"; }
  };
  template <>
  struct PizzaTopping<Foobar> {
      QString operator() const { return "this is a foobar"; }
  };
  ```

  You can even just fully-specialize member, instead of full class (to be similar to above method).

  ```
  template <>
  QString PizzaTopping<Foo>::operator() const { return "this is a foo"; }
  ```

  You can partial specialize the class.

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct PizzaTopping<std::vector<T>> {
      QString operator() const {
          return "this is a vector. and for inner type, " + PizzaTopping<T>{}();
      }
  };
  ```
- Tag dispatching (overload instead of specialization):

  ```
  template <typename T> struct Tag{};

  template <typename T>
  QString PizzaTopping(Tag<T>) { return "this is a T"; }

  QString PizzaTopping(Tag<QString>) { return "this is a qstring"; }
  QString PizzaTopping(Tag<QUrl>) { return "this is a url"; }
  QString PizzaTopping(Tag<Foobar>) { return "this is a foobar"; }

  template <typename T>
  QString PizzaTopping(Tag<std::vector<T>>) {
      return "this is a vector, and for inner type, " + PizzaTopping(Tag<T>{});
  }
  ```

  It is similar to your way with pointer (without some pitfall: you don't support reference for example).

> Is there any way to achieve my goal, so that if I or anyone else chooses to subclass, that the process of overloading `QString topping(<SomeType>);` is a little bit more straight forward?

If `PizzaTopping` is in your class (as method), you cannot extend to other types.

- Either use the specialization way if you want it to be in your class.
- Move it outside of the class and select your favorite dispatching way.